# How to retrieve attributes and username sent by the CAS server with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, cas

I have a spring boot application, which is MVC in nature. All page of this application are being authenticated by CAS SSO. 
I have used "spring-security-cas" as described at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cas-sso 
Everything working fine as expected. However, I have one problem - that is, I cannot retrieve attributes 
and username sent by the CAS server in the following @Bean. What need I do to retrieve all the attributes 
and and username sent by the CAS server?

```
@Bean
public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {

    CasAuthenticationProvider provider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
    provider.setTicketValidator(ticketValidator());
    provider.setUserDetailsService(
      s -> new User("casuser", "Mellon", true, true, true, true,
        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN")));
    provider.setKey("CAS_PROVIDER_LOCALHOST_9000");
    return provider;
}
```

Comment: If the user is successfully authenticated you can get the Principal using [`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#obtaining-information-about-the-current-user). Please check the example below section that starts with _The /secured path is mapped to the index()_ in the document shared

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You are right but first I had to implement AuthenticationUserDetailsService as describe in accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need to configure the [attributeRepository](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#authentication-attributes) source and the attributes to be retrieved, in attributeRepository section in CAS server, like:

```
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc[0].singleRow=false
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc[0].sql=SELECT * FROM USERATTRS WHERE {0}
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc[0].username=username
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc[0].role=role 
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc[0].email=email
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc[0].url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/xdb
cas.authn.attributeRepository.jdbc[0].columnMappings.attrname=attrvalue

cas.authn.attributeRepository.defaultAttributesToRelease=username,email,role
```

Check [this](https://apereo.github.io/2017/02/22/cas51-dbauthn-tutorial/#attributes) example from CAS blog.

Then you need to implement an AuthenticationUserDetailsService at the service to read attributes returned from CAS authentication, something like:

```
@Component
public class CasUserDetailService implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(Authentication authentication) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        CasAssertionAuthenticationToken casAssertionAuthenticationToken = (CasAssertionAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        AttributePrincipal principal = casAssertionAuthenticationToken.getAssertion().getPrincipal();
        Map attributes = principal.getAttributes();
        String uname = (String) attributes.get("username");
        String email = (String) attributes.get("email");
        String role = (String) attributes.get("role");
        String username = authentication.getName();
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> collection = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        collection.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
        return new User(username, "", collection);
    }
}
```

Then, adjust your authenticationProvider with `provider.setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(casUserDetailService);`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't it be `CasAuthenticationToken = (CasAuthenticationToken) authentication` instead of `CasAssertionAuthenticationToken`? Isn't the call to `getAssertion` the one that produces the assertion and not the casting of the `authentication`?